# In AWS Load Balancing and Auto Scalling when the alarm fires and another instance launched .. my application crashes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, autoscaling, aws-sdk

I have a client-server application, I put the server module on EC2 instance and made a customized alarm with the auto scaling to launch new instance based on the number of users connected to the instance..

so if the number of clients using my server application reached 5, it launches another instance.. and it worked fine..

but after launching the new instance, all the client applications crashes.. any guess why is that?

note: I tested running many clients from private network.. that means all the clients requests will appear to the server coming from the same ip (don't know if that info. help)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you using multiple zones? Sticky Sessions?

Comment: Does your application handle multiple servers? Are you serving traffic via ELB? Have you tried simulating lots of connections from multiple servers (sometimes there are a limited number of connections permitted per server)?

Comment: @datasage yes I use multiple zones and sticky sessions

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes I serve traffic via ELB, currently I'm trying to get it work with small number of connections (5 connections - 2 instances), if it worked I'll scale up the number of connections and instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem when i deployed my WCF application on more than one server on amazon behind the load balancer and after a lot of google search i found a solution to my problem in this article
http://forums.asp.net/t/1697249.aspx?WCF+Exception+The+reliable+session+was+faulted 
if you use WCF with session support the above article will help you if not please specify your type of application you published it may help others to answer you

Comment: Thanks a lot! it fixed my problem, I had to enable sessions in my client config as well, just enabling sticky sessions in ELB is not enough.. I added a property allowCookies = true as mentioned in the article u sent and it worked like a charm :)